# Dokku run with --rm flag

Tags: dokku

According to the dokku guide for schedule tasks(cron) To remove a container after dokku run we should use dokku --rm run....

I got a wierd issue with that,

when I run for example

> dokku run APP bundle exec rake db:migrate

Everything works fine,

but when trying to run it with --rm flag
I get a

> 'db:migrate APP` is not a dokku command.

Comment: Could you show the actual command (with --rm) you're running?

Comment: dokku --rm run clusves bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: Can't find definite docs on that and don't have dokku to test right now, however you may want to try `dokku run --rm clusves bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: it's not working, thinks the --rm is the app name... out: "setuidgid: fatal: unable to run --rm: file does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem (basically everything I got was an `is not a dokku command` error) and I manage to solve it by changing crontab file with the following approach.

Original example line from crontab configuration file was like:

```
0 * * * * dokku dokku --rm run app bundle exec rake a:task
```

After changing it to:

```
0 * * * * dokku --rm run app bundle exec rake a:task
```

the cron began to work as expected (e.g. I can tail mail sent by crontab by doing `tail -f /var/mail/dokku`).

I don't know exactly why this solution works, but it does.